# Daemon service in systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

I have managed to install daemon service in `/etc/systemd/system`, however I am not sure about 2 things:

1. Whether the daemon services should reside there
2. How can I elegantly check whether a daemon service is installed or not in systemd?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

**1.If the daemon services should reside there**

yes, it is the .service location. The file that you should put here is:

*mydeamon.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=ROT13 demo service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=**YourUser**
ExecStart=**pathToYourScript**

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You’ll need to:

- set your actual username after User=
- set the proper path to your script in ExecStart= (usually /usr/bin/ You can put your script here)

[creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6)

**2.How can I elegantly check if a daemon service is installed or not in systemd?**

systemctl has an is-active subcommand for this:

`systemctl is-active --quiet service`

will exit with status zero if service is active, non-zero otherwise, making it ideal for scripts:

```
systemctl is-active --quiet service && echo Service is running
```

[test Service is running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396630/the-proper-way-to-test-if-a-service-is-running-in-a-script)